# Python3 with Loop function / password exit?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new to Python and need a little help. I came across this code on here which I kind of understand and want to expand on it... but I don't know how to get out of the loop!

When you run the code and enter the specified username and password, it runs the defined function logged()... but then loops back to asking for the username again because it run the main() function again!... how can I get past this. When the correct username & password is entered, I would like to be at a point where I can add new code! Does this make sense?

```
import os
import time
#Must Access this to continue.
def main():
    while True:
        UserName = input ("Enter Username: ")
        PassWord = input ("Enter Password: ")

        if UserName == 'Bob' and PassWord == 'rainbow123':
            time.sleep(1)
            print ("Login successful!")
            logged()

        else:
            print ("Password did not match!")

def logged():
    time.sleep(1)
    print ("Welcome to ----")

main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When all matches, break out of loop and call `logged` outside the loop. Or else once the `logged` is over, you return back to the infinite loop again.

```
def main():
    while True:
        UserName = input ("Enter Username: ")
        PassWord = input ("Enter Password: ")

        if UserName == 'Bob' and PassWord == 'rainbow123':
            time.sleep(1)
            print ("Login successful!")
            break
        else:
            print ("Password did not match!")
    logged()
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you... when explained like that, it seems so obvious! much appreciated...